# How to remove mortar stains on bricks?

Tags: brick

I have a newly laid brick wall (about a week ago).

A day after the job was done, I used garden hose to wash the wall. The stains did not go away at all.

Some people suggested to spray some vinegar on and then wash again. It removed some stains but it was not a complete success, as you can see in the picture.

What is the most effective method for an amateur to remove these stains? I hope to avoid using acid.

[image]

Comment: Have you searched for brick cleaner? Usually hydrochloric acid based.

Comment: You already used acid - that's what vinegar is. And acid is how this gets cleaned up - just a question of safely using an acid you are comfortable using (which may be slower or require more repeated applications than some other acids you are not comfortable using.) Rather than spraying vinegar, I'd suggest using a rag or sponge or brush with vinegar (if vinegar is as much acid as you are comfortable using) directly on the stains. Perhaps a paint roller? That would apply more to the surface where you want it removed and less to the joints where you don't - if not used too wet.

Answer (score 1):

A dilute solution of muriatic acid or nowadays, Sure-Clean, which has acid in it too has been the go-to method of cleaning brick. Power washing will help too, but even that has been done with one form or another of a diluted acid.